# Enable MenuItems despite closed/hidden window? OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar

I am about to try how to enable a the Menubar from an application after the applications window has been closed or hidden.Weather it's closed or hidden isn't that important for me, I'll be happy with both ways.

I found this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html

and followed the instructions like that:

```
NSMenu *menu = [NSApplication sharedApplication].menu;
        [menu setAutoenablesItems:NO];
        for(id obj in [menu itemArray]) {
            NSMenuItem *menuFile = (NSMenuItem*)obj;
            [menuFile setEnabled:YES];
        }
```

This code doesn't do anything.

Why didn't this code work and how could I enable the menu after the window is closed or hidden?

I would appreciate every help.

Cheers

Comment: There's a difference between hiding the app (with its windows) or closing the last window and keeping the app in the foreground.  Sure you're still running the app as the active one?

Comment: I'd recommend to use Automatic Menu Enabling by implementing `validateMenuItem`

Comment: Yes I know that there is a difference. But as I described above - it doesn't matter if I'll close or hide the app as long as the menu is working.
No I am not running the app as the active one. An agent is the active one, because of this I'd need the menu from the other app, to "control" both applications from one menu.

Comment: I tried to use the validateMenuItem function like this:
'- (BOOL) validateMenuItem: (NSMenuItem *) menuItem
{
   BOOL enable = YES;
   return enable;
}'

but it seems to have no effect.
any other suggestions??

@vadian

Comment: The validateMenuItem method has to be implemented on an object in the responder chain. IIRC the application delegate is the responder of last resort (if nothing else (like a window or dialog) is active).